# Javascript Scope loss

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Here is my sample code for google map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'tilesloaded', function(overlayControl, zielgebiet) {
            return function(overlayControl) {
                if(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.dragend)
                MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.setOverlaysText.bind(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE, overlayControl, zielgebiet);
            }
}(this.overlayControl, this.zielgebiet));
```

initially i am using a gobal variable to retain my class's scope. As in this event Listener `this` represent `google.maps.event` class is there any better way to do this?

Now my question is i want to call setOverlayText after some time like
liek

```
setTimeout("MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.setOverlaysText.bind(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE, overlayControl, zielgebiet)", 1000);
```

doing so I again loose the `MAPSEARCH_SCOPE` and the class variables `overlayControl` and `zielgebiet` become undefined.

Comment: don't use strings within `setTimeout`

Comment: are these variables from the function closing this listener or these are the variable google populates?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.setOverlaysText.bind(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE, overlayControl, zielgebiet);
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

do‘t use this:

```
setTimeout("MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.setOverlaysText.bind(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE, overlayControl, zielgebiet)", 1000);
```

because the string been send to setTimeout won't be create a closure scope ,and when the expression  you want to execute be eval the scope will no longer exist, use the 
anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {MAPSEARCH_SCOPE.setOverlaysText.bind(MAPSEARCH_SCOPE overlayControl, zielgebiet);}, 1000)
```

so the function object will be created ,and the  closure scope will be keep